# Extracting parameters from forecast API via regex Java

Tags: java, regex, api

I'm trying to learn how to use regex correctly but am not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm trying to extract the temperature, max temp, min temp, and icon from the forecast.io API. The icon seems to be the parameter that is causing problems, as all of the other parameters work perfectly when I remove it. For the icon, I want to extract any words including dashes (i.e. partly-cloudy-night, rain, snow, ...). The order of appearance of the parameters in the API matches the way that they are called in the regex.

**Problematic regex**:

```
String re = ".*icon\":([\\-a-zA-Z]+),.*temperature\":([\\-0-9\\.]+),.*temperatureMin\":([\\-0-9\\.]+),.*temperatureMax\":([\\-0-9\\.]+),.*";
```

An example forecast string can be seen here: https://api.forecast.io/forecast/e7588e2bd6966bc7f41614e2955c5978/37.8267,-122.423

The string that I am using is further limited so that only the first instance of each property is shown (i.e. In the example there are multiple cases of "icon", in the strings I will use there will only be one instance.)

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the expression?

Comment: We need the exact text for testing the regexp.

Comment: This seems messy. Lay down the actual string and the rules for matching.

Comment: Maybe it is not the first line in the text? Try replacing `".*icon` with `"(?s).*icon`

Comment: Your string is a valid json, so you can use something like https://github.com/google/gson to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add brackets around an icon to your regexp:

```
String re = ".*icon\":\"([\\-a-zA-Z]+)\",.*temperature\":([\\-0-9\\.]+),.*temperatureMin\":([\\-0-9\\.]+),.*temperatureMax\":([\\-0-9\\.]+),.*";
```

---

But i still recommend to use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for parsing Json:

```
JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(jsonStr).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray dayArr = root.getAsJsonObject("daily").getAsJsonArray("data");
for (JsonElement elem : dayArr) {
    JsonObject elemObj = elem.getAsJsonObject();
    System.out.println(elemObj.getAsJsonPrimitive("icon") + "\t" +
            elemObj.getAsJsonPrimitive("temperatureMin") + "\t" +
            elemObj.getAsJsonPrimitive("temperatureMax"));
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion to add brackets worked. Thank you so much! I've been struggling with trying to get this to work for days.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bellow regex

```
String re = "\"(temperature|temperatureMin|temperatureMax)\":[0-9]+(\.)?[0-9]*|\"icon\":\"([a-zA-Z]|-)+\"";
```

Here
(.) means 0 or 1 occurrence of .
[0-9]+  means 1 or more occurrence of digits
[0-9]* means 0 or more occurrence of digits

Comment: This won't work because I also need to be able to capture negative temperatures ("-" literal). Again, the temperature piece works fine as is, it's just the icon that I'm having problems with.